# how to find the replace the digit which is greater than 100 using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

How to use wild card using sed ? I want to search and replace "7th column" which is greater than 100, replace it with "100"

input:-

$ cat /tmp/test.in

```
Mon Sep 14 12:48:04 IST 2015, 1
Mon Sep 14 12:50:04 IST 2015, 110
```

Expected output:

```
Mon Sep 14 12:48:04 IST 2015, 1
Mon Sep 14 12:50:04 IST 2015, 100
```

## Tired:-

$ sed -i 's/,\ 1.*/, 100/g' /tmp/test.in

```
Mon Sep 14 12:48:04 IST 2015, 100
Mon Sep 14 12:50:04 IST 2015, 100
```

but you can see when the digit "1" got replaced by "100" on the 7th column. how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '$7>100{$7=100}7' file
```

sed is not very good to do match calculation/comparison, use awk instead.

Comment: but sed has an option to replace the value on original file using "-i" option. Please tell me how to perform this action using awk.

Comment: do `awk '...'  file > tmp && mv tmp file` @ranjith

Comment: just that you ask to do it in sed :-). @Kent Why the `7` at the end and not a `1` or `$7` ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu `$7` is not correct, here we need a non-zero, not empty constant. `$7` could be zero/empty, then we missed that line. regarding `1` or `7`, I personally feel to type with right index finger more easier than left little finger... so I usually typed `7`, but same meaning as `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/,[[:blank:]]*[1-9]\{1,2\}$/b' -e '/,[[:blank:]]*100$/b' -e 's/,[^,]*$/, 100/' YourFile
```

- assuming

  - all line are in the scope (adding a filter selection as first action is easy if needed)
  - there is no space after the last number (adding the pattern if needed is easy)
  - posix compliant

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@test /tmp]$ sed 's/,\ 1..*/, 100/g' a
Mon Sep 14 12:48:04 IST 2015, 1
Mon Sep 14 12:50:04 IST 2015, 100
```

Comment: I don't want to comment on your answer, but be careful, you are playing around with `root` user.

Comment: This will not match most lines ending in numbers greater than 199. Further, it will replace lines ending in 10 through 19.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/ \S\S\S+$/ 100/' file
```

Since the last field only contains an integer, any number with 3 or more digits can be replaced with `100`.